# ld hidden symbol 'fstat64' in /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(fstat64.oS) is referenced by DSO

Tags: c++, ld

I am attempting to compile a bit of code have been presented with an error I am unsure how to deal with.

```
/usr/bin/ld: nmtest: hidden symbol `fstat64' in /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(fstat64.oS) is referenced by DSO
```

From what I have been researching it appears `fstat64` has not been exported as a symbol that can be called externally. My problem however is the library I am using has fstat64 called numerous times and I cannot edit the library to remove the call.

Does anyone have any ideas as to a possible work around for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a wrapper that calls `fstat` and export it as `fstat64`.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to go about doing that?